# Generic API interface to avoid API explosion

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, enums, api-design

I have a service in which there are many APIs (~25-30). Each API takes the request parameters and just execute the SQL and responds with the values from SQL output. Each API differs with very little parameters. (e.g. API1 and API2 differs by only one condition. API3 is grouping on f1,f2 and API4 is grouping on f1,f2,f3). Also, response of each API differs by some paramters.

I am searching for some best practices to handle this kind of situations. I also went through JOOQ which can objectify the SQL.

```
// enum for API
API {
    GET_DETAILS_BY_ID("GET_DETAILS_BY_ID", REQUEST(ID), RESPONSE(NAME)),
    GET_DETAILS_BY_NAME("GET_DETAILS_BY_NAME", REQUEST(NAME), RESPONSE(ID)),
    GET_DETAILS_BY_GROUP_ID("GET_DETAILS_BY_GROUP_ID", REQUEST(ID), RESPONSE(ID, SUM(MARKS)),;

    private String apiName;
    private APIRequest request;
    private APIResponse response;
}
```

If a client wants to call GetDetailsById then it would call 
getDetails(GET_DETAILS_BY_ID, new Request(1)). 
Interface in the service would map 1 to Id and execute the SQL

```
select name from student where id = <id>;
```

Similarly, getDetails(GET_DETAILS_BY_GROUP_ID, new Request(1)). 
Interface in the service would map 1 to Id and execute the SQL

```
select id, sum(marks) from student where id = <id> group by <id>;
```

and return name as API response.

I am thinking of making one generic API and parameters would have API enum and the request parameter values.

Any suggestions on this approach or pointers to best approach/practice would be helpful.

Comment: Well, in general when the api has methods like `GET_DETAILS_BY_XXX` then I'd expect the response to be the same no matter what `XXX` is. In that case you could also use a more complex object that describes properties of what you want to get and use the information in that request object to determine the actual call (e.g. one could pass a range of ids as well as a pattern for the name and get all students whose id is in that range and whose name matches the pattern - or you just pass a range like [x,x] to get one specific id only).

Comment: @Thomas, Response for each API is specific because returning all the details would slow down API (API can return thousands of rows which could increase I/O if we get all the fields)

Comment: Well in that case I'd not use the same base name because that indicates the response is the same. If you want a generic api you could let the caller pass information on the wanted data as well and build your response accordingly. It would basically be something silimar to [GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java)